# Unfamiliar SQL Syntax in a Scripted-Out table script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've jut recently scripted out a table from an existing DB on one of our SQL Servers, which brings back the following glorious result:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[queuemembership](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [versionnumber] [bigint] NULL,
    [queueid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [queuemembershipid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [systemuserid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [EPK[dbo]].[queuemembership]]] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm not familiar with the `EPK` bit of CONSTRAINT `[EPK[dbo]].[queuemembership]]] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

If I recreate the table from scratch I can replace `EPK` with other text, which makes me think this is some sort of external metadata or something.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: That's just a poorly named object. *Very* poorly named... The `CONSTRAINT` is called `EPK[dbo].[queuemembership]`, which when you want to reference that object, you have to escape the right brackets (`]`) and delimit identify it, resulting in `[EPK[dbo]].[queuemembership]]]`. I strongly recommend that a *better* name is used.

Comment: Can you have square brackets in an object name?

Comment: Yes, @Andrew , you can have *any* character in an object's name. You can *even* have emojis (though that can result in some very odd/interesting behaviour which is collation specific: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5e96cadf1a8fabcfe6a66b2f7a6a8d6)).

Comment: @Larnu - wow, that is seriously messed up. Although the idea of naming objects using emojis is kind of funny...

Comment: As I mentioned, it's specific to the collation choice. If the database was in a binary collation, for example, it [doesn't happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FjHZ.png), @Andrew .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've covered this in the comments, but to put it into an answer, `[EPK[dbo]].[queuemembership]]]` is a delimit identified and properly escaped value for an object (specifically a `CONSTRAINT`) called `EPK[dbo].[queuemembership]`.

This is, in truth, a very poorly named object; it contains multiple different characters that require the name to need to be delimit identified and a multiple characters that need escaping. Any of the right brackets (`]`) need escaping, in the same way that you would a single quote (`'`) in a literal string; double them up. Then, because of the said right brackets, *as well* as the left brackets (`[`) and the periods (`.`), which is a part separator, this means that the entire value needs to be delimit identified.

As a result, you end up with that value `[EPK[dbo]].[queuemembership]]]`. You can also double check this by running `PRINT QUOTENAME(N'EPK[dbo].[queuemembership]');`.

Honestly, I suggest naming you `CONSTRAINT` something better, that doesn't need delimit identification or escaping. `PK_queuemembership` is likely more than fine.

Comment: Ahhhh! Doh!!! Thanks. So obvious. Actually this was an auto-generated table from a data-sync agent. I probably wasn't really meant to see the actual auto-generated implementation.